# How do I fix exceptions that are not executing properly for ice cream flavors and number of scoops?

Tags: python

In this program I have created a class for ice cream flavors and a FlavorsError class. There is also a Scoops class and a scoops error class.

Problem 1 - if your input is greater than 3 for number of scoops it should print the scoops error message.

Problem 2- if your input is not listed under flavors it should print the flavors error message.

For both, the error messages do not appear if data does not match the class information.

Code:

```
class FlavorsError(Exception):
    def __init__ (self, message = "is not on the menu."):
        super().__init__(message)
        self.message = message
        
class Flavors(object):

    def __init__(self, Vanilla, Chocolate, Strawberry, Mint, Pistachio, Spumoni):
        self.Vanilla = Vanilla
        self.Chocolate = Chocolate
        self.Strawberry = Strawberry
        self.Mint = Mint
        self.Pistachio = Pistachio
        self.Spumoni = Spumoni

class ScoopsError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message='We do not offer that many scoops!'):
        super().__init__(message)
        self.message = message

class Scoops(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 5
        if self.count > 3:
            raise ScoopsError()

        
class Holdings(object):

    def __init__(self, Bowl, Cone):
        self.Bowl = Bowl
        self.Cone = Cone

def main():
    
    Flavors= " "
    Scoops = " "
    Holdings = " "

    
    Flavors = input("Enter a flavor of ice cream: ")
    print()
    Scoops = int(input("Enter the number of scoops: "))
    print()
    Holdings = input("Would you like a cone or bowl? ")
    print()
    print(Scoops , "scoops of" , Flavors , "in a" , Holdings)

main()
```

**Currently output:**

Enter a flavor of ice cream: peanut butter

Enter the number of scoops: 7

Would you like a cone or bowl? cone

7 scoops of peanut butter in a cone

**What the outputs should be:**

Enter a flavor of ice cream: peanut butter

Enter the number of scoops: 2

Would you like a cone or bowl? cone

peanut butter is not on the menu.

**AND**

Enter a flavor of ice cream: vanilla

Enter the number of scoops: 5

Would you like a cone or bowl? bowl

we do not offer that many scoops

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. This is not a question. If you want debugging help, please provide a [mre], and try to ask about one problem at a time.

Comment: I have the same problem for both

Comment: I tried to make the problem as simple as possible. All the classes are there but they aren't initiating

Comment: If they're essentially the same problem, then it's redundant to ask about both of them. Make a [mre] that covers both.

Comment: @user14391552 Please be kind to other people, this is a space for everyone, you want people to help you and you are not going to get help by acting like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to raise the exceptions ?

You are saving input to a variable and then printing it.

The classes you defined aren't used at all.